# How to execute a VS2008 command from Python and grab its output?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, shellexecute

I wish to run

```
tf changeset 12345
```

Using the Visual Studio 2008 Command tool. It is located in: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\"` and the command that gets launched is: `%comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86`

I would like to append the "tf changeset 12345" to it somehow and save it to a string WITHOUT first redirecting it to a file. I noticed that when I simply call it from the command line, I get GUI when I type:

```
tf changeset 12345
```

and I get the textual output when I do:

```
tf changeset 12345 > out.txt
```

I prefer not to create a file on the file system, but hopefully just read it in the "Pythonic way".

I have seen brief examples of os.system(), subprocess, but none of them seem to illustrate how to do what I want to do:

1. Run the process from a particular directory (preferably without using chdir)
2. Executing a command which contains environment variables + custom text.
3. Redirect the output without creating a temporary file.

Hopefully you can help me get close to what I want. It would help if you tested the solution on VS2008 or some other Windows program.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['tf', 'changeset', '12345'], cwd='c:/somedir', env={'SOMEENVVAR': 'SOMEVALUE', ...}, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in process.stdout:
  print line

process.terminate()
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this code I used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255126/acessing-netstat-like-data-with-net/2255159#2255159) to do the job that you're looking for. This is written in C#, and is a flexible class, you just need to change the command, look in `ps.FileName` and `ps.Arguments`, the output of the command gets redirected to a `StringBuilder` instance for parsing if so required. The shell executing command in a window is completely hidden and does not show.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thanks, but a Python solution would be nice as well.